# mysql connection error & pointer being freed was not allocated error when saving published messages

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, google-cloud-pubsub, mysql-connector-python

I'm new to python, sql and pubsub. Getting the following errors although some of the data is being written to the db.

Trying to insert data received in the callback function to a local mysql DB

It probably has something to do with cnx.execute(), I haven't been able to figure it out, example on how to solve it is appreciated

```python
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import  Error, connect
import json
    
try:
     cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        password = 'pass',
        database = 'db',
        auth_plugin = 'mysql_native_password',
    )
except Error as e:
    print('Error while connecting', e)

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path('sim', 'sub')
topic_path = publisher.topic_path('sim', 'topic')

def callback(message):
    print(f'Received {message.data}')
    message.ack()
    print(f'Acknowledged {message.message_id}')

    data = json.loads(message.data)

    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    insert_record = """
    INSERT INTO Device (deviceId, temperature, location, time)
    VALUES
    (%s, %s, point(%s,%s), %s)
    """

    record = (data['deviceId'], data['temperature'], data['Location']['lat'], data['Location']['long'], data['time'])
    cursor.execute(insert_record, record)
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()

subscriber.create_subscription(name = subscription_path, topic = topic_path)

streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f'Listening for messages on {subscription_path}')

with subscriber:
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except TimeoutError:
         streaming_pull_future.cancel()
         streaming_pull_future.result()
```

I get different errors randomly

Error 1:

```
Listening for messages on projects/sim/subscriptions/sub
Received b'{"deviceId": "63db2b39-b763-40f7-ba17-9f705e846d29", "temperature": "25", "Location": {"lat": "3.1552843960706554", "long": "101.59710065578479"}, "time": "1630478123"}'
Received b'{"deviceId": "86fb239a-f682-437e-8c67-3370894ce1de", "temperature": "27", "Location": {"lat": "2.9256061054944578", "long": "2.9256061054944578"}, "time": "1630478123"}'
Acknowledged 8
Acknowledged 7
Python(22271,0x70001584b000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f81386155d0: pointer being freed was not allocated
Python(22271,0x70001584b000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[10]    22271 abort      /usr/local/bin/python3 subscriber.py
```

Error 2:

```
Listening for messages on projects/sim/subscriptions/sub
Received b'{"deviceId": "63db2b39-b763-40f7-ba17-9f705e846d29", "temperature": "24", "Location": {"lat": "3.1552843960706554", "long": "101.59710065578479"}, "time": "1630478140"}'
Acknowledged 58
Received b'{"deviceId": "86fb239a-f682-437e-8c67-3370894ce1de", "temperature": "25", "Location": {"lat": "2.9256061054944578", "long": "2.9256061054944578"}, "time": "1630478140"}'
Received b'{"deviceId": "fba83680-7c5f-4064-9e96-f84900cae416", "temperature": "25", "Location": {"lat": "3.0318117541349343", "long": "101.48630495540324"}, "time": "1630478140"}'
Acknowledged 59
Acknowledged 60
Top-level exception occurred in callback while processing a message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 85, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "/Users/abcabcabcbac/Projects/sim/subscriber.py", line 35, in callback
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 568, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abcabcabcbac/Projects/sim/subscriber.py", line 55, in <module>
    streaming_pull_future.result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 445, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
Top-level exception occurred in callback while processing a message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 269, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 531, in cmd_query
    return self.fetch_eof_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 458, in fetch_eof_status
    'insert_id': self._cmysql.insert_id(),
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 85, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "/Users/abcabcabcbac/Projects/sim/subscriber.py", line 44, in callback
    cursor.execute(insert_record, record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 273, in execute
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(msg=exc.msg, errno=exc.errno,
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 85, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "/Users/abcabcabcbac/Projects/sim/subscriber.py", line 35, in callback
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 568, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

Comment: Please tell more about your process/scenario. You are running this from your machine or from cloud? Where you have your database, what do you want to achieve? What you mean by some data? Please add more details.